# CentOS doesn’t show my USB drive

Tags: linux, centos, usb-storage

When I attached a US drive to my computer with CentOS, the indicator lamp of the USB drive is lights. But when I type `fdisk -l` in the terminal, there is no information on the USB drive. It is as follows.

What can I do to display my USB drive in my computer?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: BA943379-FCE9-4A41-B126-8B65E9703789

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
1         2048       616447    300M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
2       616448     11102207      5G  Microsoft basic  
3     11102208    157911039     70G  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Is there anything relevant in `dmesg` just after you insert the USB drive? Please answer by [edit]ing the question.